# Python reinstallation ModuleNotFoundError, AttributeError and numerous others

Tags: python, collections, pip, attributeerror, reinstall

Recently I was working on an Instagram automated video upload project. One day I decided to run "pip install InstagramAPI". After that, everything collapsed. I couldn't launch a program using another dependency, namely instabot. I don't remember the exact error.

I ended up uninstalling pip and all dependencies, as well as reinstalling Python. I've done that multiple times. Currently trying Python version 3.10.10. I have reinstalled pip as well. I installed my first dependency, InstagramAPI. While trying to run a program using InstagramAPI, I get an error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'". Upon installing urllib3 and launching the program again, I get: AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'. I have tried numerous solutions to this particular error that I found on Stack, nothing worked. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Please provide detailed Error traceback. If the error is coming from your code, then this code hasn't been updated to Python 3.9+ (Since you said you are using 3.10 now) - `collections.MutableMapping` has been deprecated since Python 3.3, and was officially **removed since Python 3.9**.